# Problem when publishing an application on the App Store [Non-public API usage]

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, app-store

Until three weeks ago, my application could upload it to the App Store without any problem. However, Apple has refused to upload the app with a new message about Non-public API usage.

The application is developed with Xamarin in Visual Studio for Mac and has updated all the libraries and packages. Can anybody help me? Because I can not find what the problem is, nor do I see any solution. It will be something new?

Thank you all.

```
Non-public API usage:

The app references non-public selectors in AppAytoSS.iOS: 
  addTemporaryAttribute:value:forCharacterRange:, 
  addTemporaryAttributes:forCharacterRange:, behaviorWithType:, 
  defaultBaselineOffsetForFont:, defaultLineHeightForFont:, finished, 
  greekingThreshold, horizontalCornerRadius, 
  initWithSource:convolutionState:weights:, initWithType:, 
  postSession:didAddPlayer:, postSession:didReceiveData:fromPlayer:, 
  postSession:didReceiveMessage:withData:fromPlayer:, 
  postSession:didRemovePlayer:, 
  postSession:player:didChangeConnectionState:, 
  postSession:player:didSaveData:, preferredMetalContext, removeData:, 
  removeTemporaryAttribute:forCharacterRange:, setGreekingThreshold:, 
  setHorizontalCornerRadius:, setIsPrimary:, setShouldAntiAlias:, setUUID:, 
  setVerticalCornerRadius:, shouldAntiAlias, 
  temporaryAttribute:atCharacterIndex:effectiveRange:, 
  temporaryAttribute:atCharacterIndex:longestEffectiveRange:inRange:, 
  temporaryAttributesAtCharacterIndex:effectiveRange:, 
  temporaryAttributesAtCharacterIndex:longestEffectiveRange:inRange:, 
  textContainerChangedTextView:, toolTip, usesBackgroundSession, 
  verticalCornerRadius
```

Comment: Same here... Did you find a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After filling an internal issue with the Xamarin team, they advised doing the following

> adding **--linksdkonly** to the Additional mtouch arguments on the iOS Build settings page
>   As it seems that **Visual Studio** ignores the settings in GUI

I have tested it and now get my build accepted by Apple without the above error

This is the issue filed on Xamarin 
https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/5913

Answer (score 2):

We had the (exactly) same problem with an Xamarin iOS Project and where able to fix it via Setting Build/iOS Build/Linker Behaviour: Link Framework SDKs only (before Don't link) - what Jack Hua link shows as solution.

We where not able, to figure out the problem behind though. Two different MacBooks where used, one with the most recent version of XCode, Visual Studio and Xamarin Libs, the other with slightly older versions. The latter was able to create an IPA without the above described error, the updated machine was not.

However the used NugGet Packages where the same, so I think this issue is not related to them.

Comment: This issue seems to be a Xamarin issue as it only happens in their latest update.

Answer (score 0):

I find a thread where people meet the same problem with you recently:[build-status-has-changed-to-invalid-binary](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/153225/build-status-has-changed-to-invalid-binary).

So, I guess some third part nuget packages you are using has updated and using these non-public selectors that Apple not allow.

I would suggest you to get you code three weeks ago and don't update any third part nuget packages. Then submit again to check if it is the problem.

You can also compare your reference with the references people listed in that thread and find something similar. And any nuget packages related to Player(As I can see some player selector in the non-public selectors list)?